# Как оптимизировать php код?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Код задает определенную ширину ($img_width) и высоту ($img_height) и класс ($grid_num), определнным блоком ($count_block)

Это все пробегается в цикле, и счетчик ($count_block ) каждый раз увеличивается на один. Как это оптимизировать? Советовать лучше сразу с примером. Спасибо

```
    $img_width = '';
$img_height = '';
$grid_num = '';

if ($count_block == 2 || 
    $count_block == 4 || 
    $count_block == 5 || 
    $count_block == 11 || 
    $count_block == 13 || 
    $count_block == 14 || 
    $count_block == 15 || 
    $count_block == 16 || 
    $count_block == 20 || 
    $count_block == 21 || 
    $count_block == 23 || 
    $count_block == 24 || 
    $count_block == 25 || 
    $count_block == 27 || 
    $count_block == 28 || 
    $count_block == 31 || 
    $count_block == 32 || 
    $count_block == 35 || 
    $count_block == 36 || 
    $count_block == 38 || 
    $count_block == 39 || 
    $count_block == 41) {

$img_width = '100';
$img_height = '100';
$grid_num = '1';

} elseif ($count_block == 1 ||  
        $count_block == 3 ||  
        $count_block == 7 ||  
        $count_block == 8 ||  
        $count_block == 9 ||  
        $count_block == 10 ||  
        $count_block == 12 ||  
        $count_block == 17 ||  
        $count_block == 19 ||  
        $count_block == 22 ||  
        $count_block == 26 ||  
        $count_block == 29 ||  
        $count_block == 30 ||  
        $count_block == 34 ||  
        $count_block == 37 ||  
        $count_block == 42) {

$img_width = '400';
$img_height = '500';
$grid_num = '2';

}
elseif ($count_block == 6 || 
      $count_block == 18 || 
      $count_block == 33 || 
      $count_block == 40) {

$img_width = '430';
$img_height = '240';
$grid_num = '3';

}
```

Comment: посмотрите функцию in_array()

Comment: >посмотрите функцию in_array()

более того, даже если бы в php не было этой функции, самое первое, что должно прийти в голову автору - это написать ее самому

Comment: обожемоиглаза! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$imgDimension = getImgDimensionsByCountBlock($countBlock);

function getImgDimensionsByCountBlock($countBlock) {
    $rules = array(
        array(
            'validCountBlock' => array(2,4,5,11),
            'dimensions' => array(
                'width' => 100,
                'height' => 100,
                'gridNum' => 1,
            )
        ),
        array(
            'validCountBlock' => array(6,18,33,11),
            'dimensions' => array(
                'width' => 400,
                'height' => 500,
                'gridNum' => 2,
            )
        ),
        array(
            'validCountBlock' => array(3,7,8,9),
            'dimensions' => array(
                'width' => 430,
                'height' => 240,
                'gridNum' => 3,
            )
        ),
    );
    foreach($rules as $rule) {
        if(in_array($countBlock, $rule['validCountBlock'])) {
            return $rule['dimensions'];
        }
    }
}
```

По ощущениям у вас там как то все сложно, я бы держал в голове что все это возможно придется переписывать и всю логику запихал бы в функцию

Answer (score 4):

я бы написал проще. сильно проще. У Вас уже есть переменная `$grid_num`, которая должна была бы подсказать.

Итак, нужно два массива. Первый - указывает номер типа блока

```
$block_num = array( 1=> 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2 ....{тут допишите до конца});
```

второй массив хранит размеры:

```
$block_size = array(1=>array(100,100), 2=>array(40,500), 3=>array(430,240));
```

теперь внутри цикла

```
$grid_num = $blocl_num[$count_block];
$img_width = $block_size[$grid_num][0];
$img_height = $block_size[$grid_num][1];
```

и все.

Плюсы - легкая модификация размеров, легко подменить типы,  в массиве block_num легко добавить номера блоков для устранения неоднозначности.

p.s. в пхп коде мог делать мелкие ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

```
Код:

$img_width = '';
$img_height = '';
$grid_num = '';

$settings = array(
    array(
        'indexes'    => array(2, 4, 5, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 31, 32, 35, 36, 38, 39, 41),
        'img_width'  => 100,
        'img_height' => 100,
        'grid_num'   => 1
    ),
    array(
        'indexes'    => array(1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 17, 19, 22, 26, 29, 30, 34, 37, 42),
        'img_width'  => 400,
        'img_height' => 500,
        'grid_num'   => 2
    ),
    array(
        'indexes'    => array(6, 18, 33, 40),
        'img_width'  => 430,
        'img_height' => 240,
        'grid_num'   => 3
    )
);

for ($count_block = 1; $count_block < 42; $count_block++) {
    foreach ($settings as $setting) {
        if (array_search($count_block, $setting['indexes']) !== false) {
            $img_width  = $setting['img_width'];
            $img_height = $setting['img_height'];
            $grid_num   = $setting['grid_num'];
            break;
        }
    }

    print_r(array($img_width, $img_height, $grid_num));
    echo('<br>');
}

Результат выполнения: 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 430 [1] => 240 [2] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 430 [1] => 240 [2] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 430 [1] => 240 [2] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 500 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 430 [1] => 240 [2] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 1 )`введите код здесь`
```

Comment: у Вашего алгоритма кубическая сложность, как минимум.

Comment: @KoVadim больше вариантов, плохих и хороших :)

Comment: Это пример кода как не нужно писать.